# Finding best linear predictor

Tags: statistics

I am given the model $Y_i=\alpha_0+\beta_0 X_i+\epsilon_0$, where $i=1,2,...,n$, $X_i$ are fixed numbers and $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2).$ I am also given that $\sigma^2$ and the parameters $(\alpha_0,\beta_0)$ for $E(Y_i)=\alpha_0+\beta_0 X_i$ are unknown.

I have to estimate $(\alpha_0,\beta_0)$ using $(\alpha^*,\beta^*)$ which are found by minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\alpha-\beta X_i)^2.$

To find $\alpha^*$, I set $\frac{d}{d\alpha}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\alpha-\beta X_i)^2=0$ and got that $\alpha^*=\widehat{Y}-\beta^* \widehat{X}$, where $\widehat{Y}=\frac{Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_n}{n}$ and $\widehat{X}=\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}$.

However I am having a hard time finding $\beta^*$. Here is my process and where I get stuck:
$\frac{d}{d\beta}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-\alpha-\beta X_i)^2=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d}{d\beta}(Y_i-\alpha-\beta X_i)^2=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(Y_i-\alpha-\beta X_i)=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i X_i-\alpha X_i-\beta X_i^2)=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i X_i-(\widehat{Y}-\beta \widehat{X}) X_i-\beta X_i^2)=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i X_i-\widehat{Y} X_i+\beta \widehat{X} X_i-\beta X_i^2)=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i X_i-\widehat{Y} X_i+\beta (\widehat{X} X_i-X_i^2))=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i X_i-\widehat{Y} X_i+\beta (\widehat{X} X_i-X_i^2))=0$

$\sum_{i=1}^n \beta (\widehat{X} X_i-X_i^2)=\sum_{i=1}^n(\widehat{Y} X_i-Y_i X_i)$

$\beta^* =\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(\widehat{Y} X_i-Y_i X_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n(\widehat{X} X_i-X_i^2)}$

However, $\beta^*$ should equal $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\widehat{X})Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\widehat{X})^2}$.

Could someone please explain what went wrong? Thank you.

Ps I am sorry for any mistakes in typing the given information, I am not too familiar with the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track:
$$\color{blue}{\beta^* =\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(\widehat{Y} X_i-Y_i X_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n(\widehat{X} X_i-X_i^2)}}=\frac{\widehat{Y}\sum X_i-\sum Y_i X_i}{-\widehat{X}\sum X_i+2\widehat{X}\sum X_i-\sum X_i^2}=$$
$$\frac{\frac{\sum Y_i}{n} \cdot \sum X_i-\sum Y_i X_i}{-(\widehat{X} \cdot (n \widehat{X})-\sum (2\widehat{X} X_i)+\sum X_i^2)}=\frac{\widehat{X}\sum Y_i-\sum Y_i X_i}{-(\sum (\widehat{X})^2-\sum (2\widehat{X} X_i)+\sum X_i^2)}=$$
$$\color{blue}{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\widehat{X})Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\widehat{X})^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Remark: The common notation for sample average of $X$ is $\bar{X}$.

Notice that since $\sum_{i=1}^n (\bar{X}-X_i)=0$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n \bar{X}(\bar{X}-X_i)=0$

\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^n (\bar{X}X_i-X_i^2)&=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\bar{X}-X_i) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\bar{X}-X_i) -\sum_{i=1}^n \bar{X}(\bar{X}-X_i) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})(\bar{X}-X_i)\\
&=- \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2\end{align}

Similar simplification can be performed for the numerator.